# find the number of Categories for each student

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table in MySQL database:

```
FirstName  LastName  ClubName
  ALAN     STURGES    Club1
ALESIA    BLACKBURN   Club2
ALESIA    BLACKBURN, 'Club 3'
```

I want to find out the number of clubs that each student is in.then I want to consolidate the report and show just the count of students based on the number of clubs they are in.
example:

```
students     Number of Clubs
  20                1
  40                2
```

Comment: Did you get the answer for this? I have a similar situation and need to show the report exactly like above. I can only get name of clubs and no of students in it using  "SELECT `Club Name`, COUNT(*) as StudentCount  FROM clubs GROUP BY `Club Name`;

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` clauses will be your heroes.

```
/*Knowing the number of clubs per student*/
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM your_tbl GROUP BY col_student_id;
```

and

```
/*Knowing the number of students per club*/
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM your_tbl GROUP BY col_club_id;
```

Modify the above queries to suits your need results. For more information about it, read it here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

i guess

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as FULLNAME, COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLENAME 
GROUP BY FULLNAME;
```